# Send a request to an API with JWT token from iOS with an Blazor application gets error

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I had this behaviour roughly a year ago. Now, in my new application, I'm facing the same issue, but the old solution didn't work. So, I have a Blazor application with NET6. To call the API, I add the user token. I have a function that read the token from the cache or from `IAccessTokenProvider`.

```
IAccessTokenProvider _accessToken;
private async Task<AccessToken> RequestUserToken()
{
    try
    {
        var tokenResult = await _accessToken.RequestAccessToken();
        tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token);

        Console.WriteLine(token);

        return token;
    }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException aex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Exception {aex}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"AccessTokenNotAvailable Exception Exception {ex}");
    }
}
```

The application sends successfully requests to the API from Windows and Android. When I run the application on iOS devices, the token is not found and then there is an error.

[image]

How can I get (retrieve) the token in Blazor from an iOS/macOS device?

### Update

I'm running the web application on a Mac. The application is working fine with Microsoft Edge and Chrome but not with Safari.

On iPhone and iPad, I have issue with the token on Safari and Chrome. It works fine on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Check if iOS device sends the complete / correct token. Had an issue with firebase and iOS recently, where iOS clients would not send the correct token.

Comment: In the past, iOS didn't read the token. Now, I face the issue with both macOS and iOS but I can't  understand why. I mean the issue is related to the token but I don't know how to read the user token.